# When #tmp table is null ignore where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I trying to ignore my where when #tmp table is empty.

Like:

```
    create table #tmp
    (
    my_id int
    )
create table #tmp2
    (
    my_name_id int
    )



    select * from foo
    where foo_id in (select my_id from #tmp)
and foo_name_id in (select my_name_id from #tmp2)
```

And now case.
When we have ituation when one of tables is empty it will not generate any result.
#tmp is not empty
#tmp1 is empty

So my where with #tmp1 should be ignored.
Got any clue how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add additional conditions:

```
select * from foo
where (foo_id in (select my_id from #tmp) or not exists(select * from #tmp))
and (foo_name_id in (select my_name_id from #tmp2) or not exists(select * from #tmp2))
```

The general form you're adopted, however, makes it look like you're taking quite a procedural approach to SQL, where you're storing partial results in temp tables and then combining them at the end. It's usually better to write the entire desired result as a single query and let SQL Server work out how best to compute the result (and cache intermediate forms if required)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will check it asap.
My parameter is comma separeted, i tuen in into #tmp.

Comment: In that case consider checking your original parameters with the comma separated values for empty/null and doing a different query.  a) It will be faster than a NOT EXISTS on the temp tables and b) you won't get stuck with a crappy query plan based on the values you give the first time you call it (see problems with "parameter sniffing")